# How to fix printing of score values?

Tags: python

This program should display:

```
Here are your grades
Math score is 100
Science score is 90
Reading score is 70

Average grade score is 86.66
```

However with the code I have, it is displaying this:

```
Here are your grades:
Math score is 100.0
Sciencee score is 95.0
Reading score is 86.66666666666667
The average score is 86.66666666666667
```

So basically the average is correct but now the scores are not.

```
gradesFile = open("grades.txt","r")

#Establishes the variables
total = 0
numberOfLines = 0
lines = 0
print('Here are your grades:','\n')

# Creates a loop that will print out each score, until there aren't anymore
# scores to read. For example:
#Math score is 100
#Science score is 90
#and so on.
for line in gradesFile:
   numberOfLines += 1
   lines = line.strip()
   total += float(gradesFile.readline())
   score = total / numberOfLines
   print(lines + ' score is', score)

gradesFile.close
average = float(total) / (numberOfLines)
print('The average score is', average)
```

The grades.txt file looks like this:

Math

100.0

Science

90.0

Reading

70.0

Comment: We can't answer without seeing the contents of `grades.txt`. Please [edit] your question and add that.

Comment: @Chris I added it

Comment: That `grades.txt` content doesn't look right. Please make sure you're showing us an accurate [mcve]. You can mark the file as code to show exact formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Your `score` is essentially a rolling average. There's no need for that, just print it directly:

```
for line in gradesFile:
   numberOfLines += 1

   lines = line.strip()

   score =  float(gradesFile.readline())

   total += score

   print(lines + ' score is', score)
```

Comment: @sparx and then divide `total` with `numberOfLines` to get the `average`.

Comment: Adding on: if you'd like only a couple of the numbers to be displayed after the decimal point, you can look into string formatting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points).